# What site do you want to use for debugging?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to create a SharePoint project on Visual Studio 2015.

[image]

Validate gives this error:

[image]

I then updated C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc(hosts file) with the line:

```
(IP Address of server) elsanet.esl.au
```

Now I get this error:
[image]

What to do to fix this?

Answer (score 10):

In order to develop SharePoint Solutions (as opposed to Add-ins/Apps) you have to run SharePoint on the machine running Visual Studio and the Site you you debug on must be one hosted by that SharePoint Farm.

Before you continue down this road make sure you really want to create a SharePoint Solution.